# Avoid opening command history window while running selenium rc

Tags: selenium-rc

I am new to Selenium. Whenever I run the selenium script to open the browser, it additionally opens a selenium console window with the command history.Is there any way of suppressing the browser from opening this window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it possible to avoid presentation of the command history, but if you want to avoid opening additional window with logs, run Selenium RC with -singleWindow parameter.

```
java -jar path/to/server/selenium-server-standalone.jar -singleWindow
```

Comment: This is the only option.  And no, you can't get rid of the command display.